# Reassigning weakly typed variable casting

Tags: c#, .net, variables, type-inference, dynamic-typing

Given that in C# we can have the weak type var which can be of any type until it's set, is it possible to have the same var change type depending on the output of a test?

For example

```
var c = DBQuery.FindString("paramater", "data");
```

this will return NULL if the query is unsuccessful or a string if it works.

From what I can see, as FindString is has a return type of string, var c is typed as a string, despite it being null.

Is there a way to unset the typing of c so that it can then be used for

```
var c = DBQuery.FindInt("parameter", "data2");
```

Thanks

Comment: `var` is not a "weak type". "which can be of any type until it's set" --- this is not correct. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx "An implicitly typed local variable is **strongly typed** just as if you had declared the type yourself ..."

Comment: To expand: `var` is an **implicit** type. It's exactly identical to explicitly specifying the type: `var s = "foo"` is the same as `string s = "foo"`. The compiler figures it out what value to stick in the place of `var` at compile time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `var` keyword instructs the compiler to **infer** the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

The keyword you are probably  looking for is `dynamic`. The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation.

**Given this example**

```
dynamic c = "foo";
Console.WriteLine(test.GetType());

c = 2;
Console.WriteLine(test.GetType());
```

**Output**

> System.String
>   System.Int32

Nevertheless, I suggest you to adapt your code to avoid the `dynamic` type, mainly because you lose the ability to detect error at compile-time and the ability to use IntelliSense.

**Additional resources**

The `var` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx
The `dynamic` keyword: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You have understood the `var` keyword incorrectly. It's not *any type until it's set*. It's still statically typed.

It means: the compiler will figure out the type of the expression on the right-hand side of the assignement, and this will be the statically declared type of the variable.

Since `DBQuery.FindString` is declared as returning `string` (null or not), the declaration is 100% equivalent to:

```
string c = DBQuery.FindString("parameter", "data");
```

What you want to do is not possible in C#. You can declare the variable as `object` or `dynamic` and the code would work, but if you do so, you loose all design-time help such as IntelliSense (plus a runtime performance hit due to casting or dynamic typing).

Comment: This just begs the question, "why do you want to use the same variable for different types?" I smell an XY problem.

Comment: Totally agree. In addition to my answer, using the same variable name for two different things is a bad coding style.